# modify php variable name dynamically

Tags: php, variables

I want to do something like this, but smarter.

```
$armor = $row['armor'];
$elemental_armor = $row['elemental_armor'];
...
$unlock_field=mysql_result($wiki_result_set,$i,"unlock_field");

if ($unlock_field == "armor"){
    $wiki_armor = $armor;
} else if ($unlock_field == "elemental_armor"){
    $wiki_elemental_armor = $elemental_armor;
}
```

Is something like this possible?

```
$wiki_{$unlock_field} = {$unlock_field};
```

Sorry for the potentially simple question.  I am admittedly a php novice.

Comment: You can, but it's a very bad practice. Use for example arrays instead.

Comment: PHP calls this [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Comment: My code did not work when I tried it.  Can you fix my syntax/advise?  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you all for the quick help!!  Happy holidays!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$var = "wiki_{$unlock_field}";
$$var = $unlock_field;
```

Comment: `$answer .= "text" ? +1 : -1`

Comment: sure an array is way better solution, but he asked how to do var variable

Comment: I +1ed you as they are saying the array way is better, so I will trust the wisdom.  I admittedly, don't know which way is best, or what I was asking for :D

Comment: @KisnardOnline Your entire code doesn't know what it's doing. I suspect a trivial `extract` with prefixing or using a saner database interface would remove 20 lines of it.

Comment: I am making a wiki that in game players randomly unlock.  In this case monster page.  It needs to store the values for the monster, and then only show them when another table has an entry.

Comment: here is what you helped me to do: http://www.kisnardonline.com/wiki/monsters.php?name=Snake @Dynamic I went with your solution

Answer (score 1):

You can make $wiki_ as an array variable.

```
$armor = $row['armor'];
$elemental_armor = $row['elemental_armor'];
...
$unlock_field=mysql_result($wiki_result_set,$i,"unlock_field");
$wiki_[$unlock_field] = $row[$unlock_field];
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to do this. You should use an array instead... it just makes more sense.

```
$wiki = array();
$unlock_field= mysql_result($wiki_result_set,$i,"unlock_field");

$wiki[$unlock_field] = $row['$unlock_field'];
```